# What is the difference between a ND-Buffer and a G-Buffer?

Tags: javascript, webgl, deferred-rendering, webgl-extensions, webgl2

I'm noob at WebGL. I read in several posts of ND-Buffers and G-Buffers as if it were a strategic choice for WebGL development.

How are ND-Buffers and G-Buffers related to rendering pipelines? Are ND-Buffers used only in forward-rendering and G-Buffers only in deferred-rendering?

A JavaScript code example how to implement both would be useful for me to understand the difference.

Comment: Can you share links to the posts?

Comment: here a juicy one: (http://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/82591/114624.pdf)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

G-Buffers are just a set of buffers generally used in deferred rendering.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_shading) gives a good example of the kind of data often found in a g-buffer

Diffuse color info

[image: Diffuse color]

World space or screen space normals

[image: World space normals]

Depth buffer / Z-Buffer

[image: Depth buffer]

The combination of those 3 buffers is referred to as a "g-buffer"

Generating those 3 buffers from geometry and material data you can then run a shader to combine them to generate the final image.

[image: Final image]

What actually goes into a g-buffer is up to the particular engine/renderer. For example one of [Unity3D's deferred renders](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderTech-DeferredShading.html) contains diffuse color, occlusion, specular color, roughness, normal, depth, stencil, emission, lighting, lightmap, reflection probs.

An ND buffer just stands for "normal depth buffer" which makes it a subset of what's usually found in a typical g-buffer.

As for a sample that's arguably too big for SO but there's [an article about deferred rendering in WebGL on MDN](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/01/webgl-deferred-shading/)

Answer (score 4):

Choosing a rendering path is a major architectural decision for a 3D renderer, no matter what API does it use. That choice's heavily depends upon the set of features the renderer has to support and it's performance requirements.

A substantial set of said features consists of so-called [screen-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_computer_graphics#Screen_space) effects. If means that we render some crucial data about each pixel of the screen to a set of renderbuffers and then using that data (not the geometry) to compute some new data needed for a frame. [Ambient Occlusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_space_ambient_occlusion) is a great example of such an effect. Based on some spacial values of pixels we compute a "mask" which we can later use to properly shade each pixel.

Moreover, there is a rendering pass which almost exclusively relies on screen-space computations. And it is indeed [Deferred Shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_shading). And that's where G-buffer come in. All data needed to compute colour of a pixel are rendered to a G-buffer: a set of renderbuffers storing that data. The data it self (and hence meanings of G-buffer's renderbuffers) can be different: diffuse component, specular component, shininess, normal, position, depth, etc. And as part of rendering of a frame contemporary deferred shading engines use screen-space ambient occlusion (SSAO), which use data from several G-buffer's renderbuffers (usually, they are position, normal and depth).

About ND-buffers. It seems to me that it's not a widely used term (Google failed to find any relevant info on them besides this question). I believe that ND stands for Normal-Depth. They're just a specific case of a G-buffer for a particular algorithm and effect (in the thesis it's SSAO).

So using G-buffers (and ND-buffers as a subset of G-buffers) and exadepends upon shading algorithms and effects you're implementing. But all screen-space computation will require some form of G-buffer.

P.S. The thesis you've link contains an inaccuracy. Author lists an ability to implement to ND-buffers on GLES 2.0 as an advantage to the method. However it's not actually possible since GLES 2.0 doesn't have depth textures (they've been added in `OES_depth_texture` extension).

Comment: I think saying GLES 2.0 supports this feature isn't inaccurate. For all intents and purposes the majority of devices that support GLES 2.0 support all the required extensions. Maybe he should have been clearer and said GLES 2.0 with that extension but I doubt he intentionally forgot to mention that

Comment: isn't true that OES_depth_texture makes development easier, but  the D-buffer could be reconstructed also by writing into a RGB texture attachment, thought this will involves some extra calculation to get the same job done? Maybe the only thing a little bit confusing there is that isn't an equivalent of, let say, an "OES_normal_texture" extension to justify the initials ND-buffer?  BTW, is was not in my intention to criticize such a wonderful and enthusiast work, it was just an example :-)

Comment: @deblocker However one can write depth to some colour attachment, GLES 2.0 w/o extensions has at best 8-bit RGBA, which is 32 bits for 4 values (depth and 3D normal). This may result poor rendering results.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add some more informations to previvous answers.

> I read in several posts of ND-Buffers and G-Buffers as if it were a
>   strategic choice for WebGL development.

One of the most important part of deferred rendering is, if given platform supports MRT (multiple render targets). If it doesn't, you are not able to share partial calculations in shaders between each rendering and it also forces you to run rendnering as many times as you have "layers" (in case of unity 3D, it might be up to 11 times?). This could slow down your program a lot.

Read more in this question
[Is deferred rendering/shading possible with OpenGL ES 2.0 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885756/is-deferred-rendering-shading-possible-with-opengl-es-2-0)

Webgl doesn't support MRT, but it has extension:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_draw_buffers/

Also there is an extension for depth textures:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_depth_texture/

So it should be possible to use deferred rendering technique, but its speed is hard to guess.

Comment: I will take this as a clear answer to my secondary question about the mobile devices. THX